# Question about graphene-django mutation documentation

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

While I've been able to make my application work, I have some concerns about doing things the right way. Therefore there is something I "do not understand" :

In the documentation, [here](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/mutations/#simple-example), in the `QuestionMutation` class, there is a `question` attribute. What does that actually mean ? It says that it defines the response and I don't understand what this means.

### Code from the documentation :

```py
class QuestionType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Question


class QuestionMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        # The input arguments for this mutation
        text = graphene.String(required=True)
        id = graphene.ID()

    # The class attributes define the response of the mutation
    question = graphene.Field(QuestionType)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, text, id):
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=id)
        question.text = text
        question.save()
        # Notice we return an instance of this mutation
        return QuestionMutation(question=question)
```

And in my code I've been able to do this :

### My type :

```py
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_active',
            'group_ids',
        )

    full_name = graphene.String()           # Python property
    full_identification = graphene.String() # Python property
```

### My mutation :

```py
class UpdateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    # --------> I could comment these and no problem. Why ? <--------
    # id = graphene.ID()
    # username = graphene.String()
    # email = graphene.String()
    # first_name = graphene.String()
    # last_name = graphene.String()
    # is_active = graphene.Boolean()

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID()
        username = graphene.String()
        email = graphene.String()
        first_name = graphene.String()
        last_name = graphene.String()
        is_active = graphene.Boolean()

    class Meta:
        output = UserType

    @login_required
    def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=kwargs['id'])
        for attr, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(user, attr, value)
        user.save()
        return user
        # I'm not returning explicit UserType, is it a problem ?
        # I actually do it with the Meta class. I guess it is the same for this ?
```

and it works whereas I didn't specify anything for the response attributes. And I don't even return the same kind of thing.
Can someone explain if I'm doing it wrong ?

You can see here that if I call this mutation :

```
mutation {
  updateUser (
    id: 42
    username: "updated_user"
    firstName: "updated"
    lastName: "user"
    email: "updated.user@test.com"
  ) {
    id
    username
    firstName
    lastName
    email
  }
}
```

I'm able to get this answer even without return values :

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateUser": {
      "id": "42",
      "username": "updated_user",
      "firstName": "updated",
      "lastName": "user",
      "email": "updated.user@test.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked the question [HERE](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/1066) and it appears that there is more information about these configuration [THERE](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/stable/_modules/graphene/types/mutation/).

Finally, since I've set the `ouput = UserType` and `model = User`, my `UserType` and `User` classes are [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and it works like a charm even without defining return fields (the ones commented in the question).

In other words, this sample of code appears to be a correct way to do this, and the official documentation doesn't do it like this but it is intented to work like this too (as you can read in the [code docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/stable/_modules/graphene/types/mutation/)).

```py
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_active',
            'group_ids',
        )

    full_name = graphene.String()           # Python property
    full_identification = graphene.String() # Python property
```

```py
class UpdateUser(graphene.Mutation):
        # We can omit return fields since UserType is defined as output ('output = UserType')
        # and UserType has already defined fields in its class.

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID()
        username = graphene.String()
        email = graphene.String()
        first_name = graphene.String()
        last_name = graphene.String()
        is_active = graphene.Boolean()

    class Meta:
        output = UserType

    @login_required
    def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=kwargs['id'])
        for attr, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(user, attr, value)
        user.save()
        return user
        # Returning a User can be done since it is linked to the UserType and we
        # said we return a UserType with 'output = UserType'
```